# How to record what a user clicks on

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm looking to build a site which will have multiple options, for example;

NOTE** These are images not any forms or input type

Pick from one of the 5 images

Pick from one of the 3 images

Pick from one of the 2 images

Pick from one of the 6 images

and so on...

What I need to do is record which option (image) the user clicked on and then output a message.

For example if you picked a b c d, msg = hello

I'm not sure how to record this data, thanks!

Comment: You asked super general question, break down your task into smaller ones and solve them separately. 1) Detect clicks by JS 2) Send AJAX request with data 3) Process it with PHP 4) Store in DB

Comment: Apologies, I should have included some of my own code, I didn't know if there was any php function that could do it all

Comment: I agree with Andrey you should use ajax to send data and call php to process it and store in DB.

Comment: @user2058820 what do you mean by PHP function? There is no PHP functions for such high level tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could link each image to a seperate page or reload the current page with a query string appended for example adding the following to your images as links

`<a href="page.php?set=1&image=3"><img src="set1-image3.png" /></a>`

You could then save this information using PHP by processing only if the GET string contains the parameters **image** and **set** and could then split out which set/image has been clicked this way.

You could also use this to choose which image set to show on the screen (show set 2 if set=1 is in the query string etc.)

Using `$_GET['set']` and `$_GET['image']` you would have access to this information very easily in PHP.

For example you could do:

```
if( isset($_GET['image']) && isset($_GET['set']) ) {

echo "You clicked image" . $_GET['image'] . " from set " . $_GET['set']; 

}
```

That would be the only pure PHP answer. The other way to do this is with Ajax or JavaScript but I'm guessing by your part about it being done in PHP this may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks I shall use ajax that method seems better else people could edit the url if I used the first and it would break my operation

Comment: Hi user2058820. I would agree Ajax would be your best bet, however as a pure PHP solution it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter to the link you click.
For example `<a href="page2.php?clickedImage=1"><img></a>`

In page2.php you could read that variable using:

```
$_REQUEST["clickedImage"]
```

For example:

```
<p>The clicked image is: <?php echo $_REQUEST["clickedImage"] ?>
```

Comment: Good luck man! Feel free to come back to us if you need further assistance!